# Magento Block Missing

Tags: xml, magento, block, php

I seem to have lost the block on my page that contains the products. I did install a vertical navigation, but i'm not sure that that had anything to do with it. I am adding products, have checked that they're displayed as in-stock etc, but they're not appearing. If I even type a description on the category this also doesn't appear. If I go to the specific URL of the product page too they still don't show. I have turned on the path hints and it looks like that block is just missing? HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly ensure you are working with the compiler and caches off and refresh the Magetno cache and Cache Storage after each change you make.

The two files you need to study are your theme's local.xml file and your theme's  list.phtml and view.phtml files for products and categories.

Stick this code at the end of /app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/layout/local.xml and see if it makes a difference:

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                    <!--
                        <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>9</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>2</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                    -->
                </block>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <!-- <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/su.phtml</template></action> -->
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                    <!--
                        <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>3</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>2</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>3</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>9</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>grid</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                    -->
                </block>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference
</catalog_category_layered>
```

[This code is lifted from teh MAgento default XML for the category view page so by putting it at the end of local.xml it is an attempt to add all the blocks back in]

Then look at app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/catalog/catagory/view.phtml and ensure it has somewhere the line

`<?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>`

If the product blocks still aren't showing, search for `name="product_list"` and `category.products` in all your xml files to see if some module is changing or removing the block.

If it still isn't there, switch to the Magento default theme just to check that is there in the default theme. If it isn't, check your category settings and start disabling third party modules until it comes back.

**EDIT

This is the original code for app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/catalog.xml, check that you have this code in that file:

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                    <!--
                        <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>10</limit></action>
                        <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>8</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>10</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>20</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>30</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>16</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>24</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>grid</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                    -->
                </block>
                <!--action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action-->
                <action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <!-- <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/su.phtml</template></action> -->
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                    <!--
                        <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>10</limit></action>
                        <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>8</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>10</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>20</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>30</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>16</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>24</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>grid</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                    -->
                </block>
                <!--action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action-->
                <action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I had the code you showed above in my 'catalog.xml' file (not local.xml) only I think I had removed something important. I copied and pasted your code and replaced what I had and it worked!! THANK YOU!

Comment: I spoke too soon! I had it working then hit 'refresh' and it disappeared and I can't get it back again. I really don't think I changed anything between the refresh, and I have tried flushing my magento cache and storage. Aghh :(((

Comment: Update: It works if I change the 'layout' to 'default', but if I have the layout as 'modern' (my theme) it does not show. Therefore I am missing something under my modern template. Any idea what I am looking for to fix this. You mention 'check your category settings' - what do you mean by this?

Comment: There is a file app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/catalog.xml - make sure that file has the original code in it: I added it to my answer above. Also, check to see if you have file app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/local.xml, if you do, check it for any updates that file is making to the catalog_category_default or catalog_category_layered blocks. I am pleased it worked for you a little bit. PLease keep percevering, I think you are close. It is strange that it worked and now it doesn't so check teh caches and filenames and design settings carefully.